# How to save many to many relation in nestjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs

I have two entities. `Post entity` and `Category entity`, which has `ManyToMany` relation.
My question is how to save many to many relations. What I did is I created a many-to-many relation in a way where we can add custom properties too. For that I created `CategoryPost` entity which is the junction table for `Post Entity` and `Category Entity`

`PostEntity.ts`

```
import { CategoryPost } from "src/categoryAndPost/category-post.entity";
import { User } from "src/user/user.entity";
import { BaseEntity, Column, Entity, JoinColumn, ManyToOne, OneToMany, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from "typeorm";

@Entity({name: 'post'})
export class PostEntity extends BaseEntity{
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number

    @Column()
    body: string

    @ManyToOne(() => User, (user: User) => user.posts, {eager: true})
    @JoinColumn({name: 'user_id'})
    user: User

    @OneToMany(() => CategoryPost, categoriesPosts => categoriesPosts.post, {cascade: true})
    categoriesPosts: CategoryPost[]
}
```

`CategoryPost.ts`, which is junction for `Category` and `Post` Entities

```
import { Category } from "src/category/category.entity";
import { PostEntity } from "src/post/post.entity";
import { BaseEntity, Entity, JoinColumn, ManyToOne, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from "typeorm";

@Entity({name: 'category_post'})
export class CategoryPost extends BaseEntity{
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number

    @ManyToOne(() => PostEntity, post => post.categoriesPosts)
    @JoinColumn({name: 'post_id'})
    post: PostEntity

    @ManyToOne(() => Category, category => category.categoriesPosts)
    @JoinColumn({name: 'category_id'})
    category: Category
}
```

`Category.ts`

```
import { CategoryPost } from "src/categoryAndPost/category-post.entity";
import { BaseEntity, Column, Entity, OneToMany, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from "typeorm";

@Entity()
export class Category extends BaseEntity{

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number

    @Column()
    label: string

    @OneToMany(() => CategoryPost, categoriesPosts => categoriesPosts.category, {cascade: true})
    categoriesPosts: CategoryPost[]
}
```

Now `Category` table already consists of some values like React, Javascript, Python. Post can be related to one or more category. So while creating a post I want to insert the post category too. So for that I did this.
`PostController.ts`

```
import {Body, Controller, Get, Post} from '@nestjs/common'
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { CategoryRepository } from 'src/category/category.repository';
import { UserRepository } from 'src/user/user.repository';
import { CreatePostDto } from './dto/create-post.dto';
import { PostEntity } from './post.entity';
import { PostService } from './post.service';

@Controller('/post')
@UseGuard(AuthGuard())
export class PostController{
    constructor(private postService: PostService, @InjectRepository(UserRepository) private userRepository: UserRepository, @InjectRepository(CategoryRepository) private categoryRepository: CategoryRepository){}
    @Post('/create')
    async createPost(@Body() createPostDto: CreatePostDto, @getUser: user): Promise<PostEntity>{
        const category1 = await this.categoryRepository.findOne({label: createPostDto.category1})
        const category2 = await this.categoryRepository.findOne({label: createPostDto.category2})
        
        return this.postService.createPost(createPostDto, user, category1, category2)
    }

    @Get()
    async getPost(){
        return this.postService.getPost()
    }
}
```

`PostService.ts`

```
import { Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";
import { InjectRepository } from "@nestjs/typeorm";
import { CreatePostDto } from "./dto/create-post.dto";
import { PostEntity } from "./post.entity";
import { PostRepository } from "./post.repository";

@Injectable()
export class PostService{
    constructor(@InjectRepository(PostRepository) private postRepository: PostRepository){}

    createPost(createPostDto: CreatePostDto, user, category1, category2): Promise<PostEntity>{
        return this.postRepository.createPost(createPostDto, user, category1, category2)
    }

    async getPost(){
        const post = await this.postRepository.findOne("3")
        return post
    }
}
```

`PostRepository.ts`

```
import { EntityRepository, Repository } from "typeorm";
import { CreatePostDto } from "./dto/create-post.dto";
import { PostEntity } from "./post.entity";

@EntityRepository(PostEntity)
export class PostRepository extends Repository<PostEntity>{
    async createPost(createPostDto: CreatePostDto, user, category1, category2): Promise<PostEntity>{
        const {body} = createPostDto
        const post = new PostEntity()
        post.body = body
        post.user = user
        
        post.categoriesPosts = [category1, category2]
        await post.save()
        return post
    }
}
```

After doing

```
........
........
await post.save()
return post
```

It sends response as

```
{
    "body": "post 8",
    "user": {
        "id": 1,
        "username": "John"
    },
    "categoryPosts": [
        {
            "id": 4,
            "label": "Javascript"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "label": "React"
        }
    ],
    "id": 10
}
```

then in junction table, post_id gets saved but category_id, which is `null`.

`JunctionTable`

```
id    post_id    category_id
 1       10            null
 2       10            null
```

Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: Does removing custom names you have given to tables and entities solve the problem?

Comment: No. Could you create one repo or have some repo that you can share which shows many to many relationship with custom properties.

Answer (score 1):

its because you are saving all category object, change repository like this:

PostRepository.ts

```
import { EntityRepository, Repository } from "typeorm";
import { CreatePostDto } from "./dto/create-post.dto";
import { PostEntity } from "./post.entity";

@EntityRepository(PostEntity)
export class PostRepository extends Repository<PostEntity>{
    async createPost(createPostDto: CreatePostDto, user, category1, category2): Promise<PostEntity>{
        const {body} = createPostDto
        const post = new PostEntity()
        post.body = body
        post.user = user
        
        post.categoriesPosts = [category1.id, category2.id] // Or "post.categoriesPosts = [category1.category_id, category2.category_id]" depend on your dto, it should be id of category
        await post.save()
        return post
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have two entities and want to save both by a save method, you can use something like this(cascade: ['insert']):

Post.entity.ts

```
  @OneToMany(() => CategoriesPosts, (categoriesPosts) => categoriesPosts.post, {
    eager: false,
    cascade: ['insert'],
  })
  categoriesPosts: categoriesPosts[];
```

Comment: I've tried all using cascade: ['insert'], cascade: true, but don't know what is the issue, still not working. Could you make simple crud operation with post and category entity that has many to many relation and make it in a way, where we can add custom properties too or you can clone and have a look into my github repository. Here's the link to the repo. I've used postgres database. https://github.com/thapaliyaprasanga/advance-queries

Comment: sure but give me some hours